# Android: How to put a textview in front of a button

Tags: android

I want to put a textview in front of a button, I couldn't do it, what I've tried:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_alert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alert" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to do it because I want the ripple effect when I click in the button, in the same time I want that show a counter in textview

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:elevation` on the `TextView` to put it in front of the `Button`.
In this way you keep the effect when button is clicked.

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:background="@color/colorButton"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="This is a button"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `Button`'s XML:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_timer"
```

Comment: Try removing the `android:layout_alignParentRight/End` lines from the `TextView` and add `android:layout_alignParentLeft=true`

Answer (score 0):

You can change to FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_alert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/alert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|end|center_vertical"
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Or easy move `TextView` after insert `Button` ^^

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_alert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aleart" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```